# How to save all binary web browser traffic

Tags: linux, firebug

I'm using Firebug and NetExport on Linux to save all web browser communication (mostly HTTP and HTTPS requests and responses). However, in my `.har` file I see messages like this:

```
The resource from this URL is not text: http://...
```

Instead of these messages I want to see the actual, full binary content (not even a single bit transformed or changed or lost). How do I get that?

I have root access on the local machine. A solution using Chrome or Firefox is fine.

Please don't recommend that I download binary files manually, there are too many of them, and I need to time the downloads perfectly, with the correct set of cookies (which may expire by the time I download manually). Please don't recommend non-Linux solutions, I have access only to Linux systems. Please don't recommend Wireshark (or tcpdump), because it can't save decrypted HTTPS traffic if I don't have the private key of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `about:config` I've set `extensions.firebug.cache.mimeTypes` to a space-separated list of MIME types, restarted Firefox, and everything got saved.

```
application/x-shockwave-flash image/gif image/jpeg image/png application/octet-stream
```

Please note that some documents are still missing from the `.har` file, I get this:

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://...
```

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. You may want to accept that answer then.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: It's too early to accept my own answer, I have to wait 2 more days before the site lets me do it.